# 'LOOKUPVALUE' does not support comparing values of type Number with values of type True/False

Tags: powerbi, dax, lookup

I'm quite new in using DAX in PowerBi and I need to perform the following dax function:

```
Latest Detailed =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    EXAM_REPORT[ACTUAL_EXAM_DATE],
    EXAM_REPORT[CES EXAM.EXAM_TYPE_SR_KEY],
        EXAM_REPORT[CES EXAM.EXAM_TYPE_SR_KEY] = 2,
    EXAM_REPORT[CES EXAM.EXAM_SIGNOFF_DATE],
        ISBLANK ( EXAM_REPORT[CES EXAM.EXAM_SIGNOFF_DATE] ) = FALSE,
    EXAM_REPORT[ASSET_GUID],
        [ASSET_GUID] = [ASSET_GUID]
)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

**Function 'LOOKUPVALUE' does not support comparing values of type Number with values of type True/False. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.**

I’ve tried converting everything to strings and also tried VALUE as well, but nothing changes.

Could you please help me? How can I do in a way that all the values share the same datatype?

Answer (score 0):

[LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) has a different signature than what you are using:

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
    <result_columnName>,
    <search_columnName>,
    <search_value>
    [, <search2_columnName>, <search2_value>]…
    [, <alternateResult>]
)
```

Your Code:

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
    <result_columnName>,
    <search_columnName>,
    <search_columnName> = <search_value>
)
```

And `FALSE` must be `FALSE()`, but the condition is inappropriate anyway.

Comment: `EXAM_REPORT[ASSET_GUID]` is a column and `[ASSET_GUID]` must be a measure? But using the same name for column and measure isn't allowed in Power BI.